# Linux/bash Piping and redirection

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I have a question from the book "unix/linux your ultimate guide" it asks

Suppose there is a program named "prog" that outputs on both stderr and stdout. Give a single command to run "prog" with the 'o' option and the string 'arg' passed as its only argument, where it takes its stdin from the output of the program "progBefore", where "prog"s stdout is ignored, and "prog"s stderr is given to the program "progAfter" through "progAfter"s stdin. Do not use any temporary files.

Here is what i tried:

```
prog -o 'arg' < `progBefore` 1>/dev/null 2> progAfter
```

Any help would be appreciated thank you

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is this doing?

```
prog -o 'arg' < progBefore 1>/dev/null 2> progAfter
```

It is calling the program `prog`, taking input from the *file* `progBefore`, passing `stdout` to `/dev/null` (which ignores it) and passing `stderr` to the *file* progAfter.  You are using file redirection when you should be using pipes:

```
progBefore | prog -o 'arg' 2>&1 1>/dev/null | progAfter
```

A *pipe* (more correctly, an *anonymous pipe*) indicated by `|` takes the `stdout` from the program on the left and sends it to the `stdin` of the program on the right.

`2>&1` redirects `stderr` to whatever `stdout` is pointing at, note that the order is important.